# can anyone suggest why re.search is failing (returning NoneType) on a particular line in a file? This line appears identical to other lines

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, file-io

I have a text file where each file line contains multiple tab separated fields. I wish to write a new file which excludes particular lines from the file, based on the content of the fields. In order to do this, I have used the following code which reads every line from a file called `Names_allVall.txt` and either writes, or does not write each line to a new file `All_v_all_nocells(subsetRejecterinputfile).txt` based on the presence of a specific three character string:

```
named_blast_list = open("Names_allVall.txt", "r")
specieslines = named_blast_list.readlines()
finalfile = open("All_v_all_nocells(subsetRejecterinputfile).txt", 'w')

lineread = 0
for line in specieslines:
    print line
    regexsearch = re.search('(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)\s(\S*)', line)
    query_group = regexsearch.group(1)
    subject_group = regexsearch.group(2)
    lineread += 1
    print 'reading line ', lineread
    print query_group
    print subject_group

    if query_group[0:3] == 'AHI' or query_group[0:3] == 'AAN':
        print "Removed line: " + line
        missed += 1
    elif subject_group [0:3] == 'AAN' or subject_group[0:3] == 'AHI':
        print "Removed line: " + line
        missed += 1
    else:
        finalfile.write(line)
        written += 1
```

So, the file which I am reading the data from is `Names_allvsall.txt`. Each line in this file has the following format:

```
VCM1b_00048 ACF15925.1  44.66   103 57  0   36  138 35  137 1e-16   72.8    VCM1b-phage     Enterobacteria-phage-13a
```

Hence, the regex used should be able to identify each of the 14 fields, where each field is specified by `(\S*)` in the regex, and each of the thirteen tabs, specified by `\s` in the regex.

Indeed, for the majority of lines in the file, the program works fine; it reads the lines from `Names_allVall.txt` and only writes the lines which do not contain `'AHI'` or `'ANN'` to the file `All_v_allnocells(subsetRejecterinputfile).txt`. However, for one particular line of the file I hit an error message:
 `query_group = regexsearch.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

I know that this error message occurs when re.search fails to identify the regex pattern in the line it is analysing. I included the print statement `print line` in order to see if the line in the file is being read 'correctly' and interestingly it isn't.
The line, copied and pasted directly from the file into this window is: `VCM1b_00048    ACY66696.1  40.18   112 67  0   25  136 24  135 4e-16   71.2    VCM1b-phage     Klebsiella-phage-KP32`

However when `print line` is executed on this line it prints `VCM1b_00048   AEH41052.1  38.66   119 73  0` to the console, as if only half the line has been read!

Initially I thought this could be some strange 'invisible character situation' where there is some random whitespace character insertion causing the regex to fail on this line. However, I am pretty sure this is not the case. I looked at the program in vim, using `set list` and other various ways to show all characters, but this line looks identical in layout to all the other lines which work fine.

Interestingly I have tried removing the line, and the one above, but still the same error occurs suggesting it may not be the line itself, but maybe a problem with the file?. If anyone can offer help I will be very thankful.

Comment: define your regex as raw string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that didn't work.

Comment: note that your regex matches also the lines which has only 14 spaces.

Comment: The 2 lines that you mention are actually different. The one that you say is copied directly from the file starts with `VCM1b_00048 ACY66696.1`, while the one from the print statement starts with `VCM1b_00048 AEH41052.1`. The second column is different, so it would seem that these are different lines.

Comment: I used your "strange" line, with your regex and it matches. Can you provide a link where we can download your file or at least an **exact** copy of the problematic part of the file? (Off topic: You might want to think of a more readable and shorter regex.)

Answer (score 0):

If only the first 2 blocks are of any interest for your filtering, use `re.match(r'(\S*)\s(\S*)', line)` (`match` matches the beginning of the line), or even simplier `query_group, subject_group = line.split()[:2]`.

If your line has fewer than 14 entries, or a double space, or even spaces instead of tab, your regexp may not return a result.